# Highcharts - Plot years on x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to plot a line on x axis when ever a new year starts. I've been trying to modify this code but i cant find a solution without "hard coding" the value on the plotLines. Thanks for the help.

```
 xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{ 
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 
            dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
        }],
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over your chart data to create the needed year options array!